# Missing HTTPOnly Cookie Attribute in Laravel 7

Tags: php, http, cookies, openvas, laravel

I have a Laravel site, I thought I patched this issue already.

I got these in my `session.php`

```
'secure'    => true,
'http_only' => true,
```

But OpenVas still detected that I still need to it.

[image]

It also listed it 3 times

[image]

Am I missing anything else ? or this is a potential **false** positive from OpenVas ?

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php):

> **httponly**
>   If set to TRUE then PHP will attempt to send the httponly flag when setting the session cookie.

From your code:

```
'http_only' => true,
```

Thus, it looks like you spelled it wrong, i.e. you spelled `http_only` whereas it should be `httponly`.